# Null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsdata, ciimage

I have been using this to convert a CIImage to NSData for ages:

```
  NSData *data = [imageRep representationUsingType: NSPNGFileType
                            properties:nil];
```

Now on El Capitan I have this error on the second line:

```
Null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument
```

I can solve that by using an empty array on the properties, like this:

```
NSData *data = [imageRep representationUsingType: NSPNGFileType
                                      properties: @{}];
```

but I am suspecting that this can cause me problems in the future.

Is this the correct way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is this the correct way to solve this problem?

Yes.

There appear to be a few places in the API which accepted `nil` values rather than an empty collection even though it was not documented as valid. The non-nil annotations added by Apple to better support inter-working with Swift are just highlighting these.

Comment: thanks. I was just wanting to know if that was ok. THANKS.